# Confirm that a dns zone is served by a nameserver

Tags: dns, tools, nameserver

We currently have a domain which has custom nameservers. Our host has their own nameservers.

I'd like to switch our domain to use our host's nameservers for a while. Our host tells me that their nameservers hold a replica of our dns zone, but I'd like to confirm this before I switch.

Is there a command line tool I can use that I can use to answer the question *"does this nameserver know the dns zone of this domain?"*

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Linux/OS X, you can do `dig @nameserver.to.test a www.mydomain.com` on the command line, which should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Not a command line tool, but if you visit http://www.gwebtools.com/ns-spy/ and add your nameserver after the trailing slash e.g.

- http://www.gwebtools.com/ns-spy/udns1.ultradns.net

  or
- http://www.gwebtools.com/ns-spy/ns1.servage.net

and then select the domain you need to view, you'll be able to see that information.

Comment: Thanks. Hard to see, as there are 37 pages of hosts and no ordering! Useful tool though

Comment: @adam I agree it's tough to find your way! But it's very handy if you're on a non linux box or don't like the command line.